# Relationship between Euler Phi Function of Prime Power and Little Fermat theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Yesterday, my friend got a task from his lecturer. The task is to show whether there is a relationship between those two theorem or not. I thought there must be a relationship between these two, because it takes the same requirement ($a$ and $n$ [or $p$] must be coprime). But I don't know how to figure it out formally.

We know that $$a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$$ given $a$ and $n$ coprime. Then, if we take $n=p^k$ with $p$ prime and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, from Euler Phi Function of Prime Power we got
$$\phi(p^k)=p^{(k-1)}(p-1).$$
Finally, we got
$$a^{p^{(k-1)}(p-1)}\equiv 1\mod p^k \quad(1)$$
If we use $k=1$ on $(1)$, then
$$a^{(p-1)}\equiv1\mod p \quad(2).$$ Since $a$ is coprime with $p^k$, then $a$ is coprime with $p$, thus we got Little Fermat theorem.

My question is if $k>1$, is there any way to simplify $(1)$ to $(2)$? What theorem should be used?

Comment: You can simplify $(1)$ to $(2)$ using Euler, i.e., $a^{|G|}= 1$ for the group $G=(\Bbb Z/n)^{\times}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910387/understanding-proof-of-eulers-theorem) for an easy proof. So both is just a corollary of Euler's Theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for the proof, but I still didn't get the formal reason of why $p^k$ can change to $p$ in the RHS.

Comment: $(2)$ is just a special case of $(1)$ by setting $k=1$. The other way is not true. $(1)$ is certainly not a special case of $(2)$. It follows more generally from Euler's Theorem. More concretly, you always have $\phi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1)$, but for $k=1$ you have $\phi(p)=p-1$.